# Format numbers with some pattern

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I am looking for some typical implementation as below:

I need my Price **EditText** Field always take values from behind, like:

Initially, **EditText** is having value 0 by default,

Now when I start typing, say when I press `1` from number keypad,

it should result in printing `0.01`.

Next, when I press `2`,

it should print as `0.12`

Next, I press `3`

it should print as `1.23`
...
and so on..

Maximum it should not be able to type value of more than `9999.99`..

Is there anyone with good with formatting skills ?

Comment: Little complex. use `addTextChangedListener` . Add your logic in `onTextChanged` section. `If length==1` then print `0.0n`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I know I have to use `TextChangeListener`. I am remaining with the logic of `onTextChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need precision upto 2 digits after decimal:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // handle empty editText value and zero
  double etValue = Double.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
  String input = s.toString();
  int len = input.length();
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        etValue *= 10;
        etValue += Double.valueOf("0.0"+input.charAt(i));
    }
  editText.setText(String.valueOf(etValue));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying with this answer.